# let pthread finish without the function waiting for it?

Tags: c, pthreads

The specs say the function "MUST NOT block waiting for the thread or processes to finish. In other words, typically,function() will return before the child processes and the worker thread have completed." 
How can I accomplish that? Saying pthread_join makes the function wait for the pthread to end, and without it, the thread is cancelled before it does all the work.

Thanks.

Comment: I am writing a program for my programming class. The function spawns multiple processes and only one thread, but it's supposed to not wait for neither the processes nor the thread to end.

Comment: What is supposed to `"not wait for neither the processes nor the thread to end"`??

Comment: Just saying...if `pthread_join` makes the calling thread wait, and you don't want the calling thread to wait...seems pretty clear what you need to *not* do yet.  *At least, not until the right time.*  Do it right before you need the results.

Comment: The function mapreduce_map_all(). It spawns processes and a thread but  it should be allowed to return before the child process or the thread have completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me this sounds like you will have to store a reference to the thread in a container of threads, which is either global or returned by the function and kept by the caller. Then, at the very end of your process (but possibly longer after your function has returned), you call `pthread_join` on all threads in that container to ensure they are properly finished.

Comment: pthread_detach()?  The thread will be reclaimed by the OS when it finishes.